# Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.18 server does not reload the updated keystore with certificates

Tags: ssl, activemq-artemis

Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.18 does not reload the updated keystore with certificates. Previously we used 2.17 and it was working fine. But after the upgrade to 2.18 the Artemis instance continues to serve requests with the certificates that were provided at the startup.
The keystore file changes hourly.

The exception on the client is:

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Tue Sep 07 04:10:33 UTC 2021
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.valid(CertificateValidity.java:277)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:683)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifyValidity(BasicChecker.java:190)
```

Exception on the server side is:

```
2021-09-06 09:30:41,315 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222208: SSL handshake failed for client from /x.x.x.x:x: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown.
```

After Artemis server is restarted the new certificates are picked up and the Artemis instance serves the requests for one hour more until the certificates expire.

I am wondering if an additional configuration had to be applied. Or if there is a way to reload the keystore without Artemis server restart.

Comment: Are you using `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.CachingSSLContextFactory`?

Comment: @DomenicoFrancescoBruscino, we use Jboss messaging subsystem to connect artemis remotely. So I am not sure which ContextFactory is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior was changed due to [ARTEMIS-3117](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3117). Previously an instance of `javax.net.ssl.SSLContext` was created for *every* connection. This would implicitly pick up any changes to the keystore and truststore for any new connection. However, this was rather inefficient and therefore didn't scale well with lots of connections. The behavior was changed so that just one `javax.net.ssl.SSLContext` is created for each acceptor. However, you can still update your keystore & truststore on disk and update the broker without a restart. Simply use the `reload` management operation on the acceptor. This is available via JMX, the web console, Jolokia, etc.

Here's an example `curl` command you can use with Jolokia:

```
curl --user admin:admin --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"type":"exec", "mbean":"org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"0.0.0.0\",component=acceptors,name=\"artemis\"", "operation":"reload"}' http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia/exec
```

Of course you'll want to adjust the username & password as well as the broker and acceptor names for your environment.

Comment: Justin, thanks a lot for the quick response! I assume that the following REST call should work If I specify acceptor and  broker names correctly: curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d  '{ "type": "EXEC", "mbean": "org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"0.0.0.0.\",component=acceptors,name=\"artemis-secure\","operation": "reload" }' http://x.x.x.x:8161/console/jolokia/exec

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks, Justin, it worked ! I am happy now:)